# Trying to edit specific sharedpreferences from different activity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

So I have an application and i am trying to get one activity's shared preferences from a different activity. I cant use defaultSharedPreferences. Here is my code:

```
thisd = ma.
    getSharedPreferences(
            user, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Where thisd is the shared preferences, user is the specific sharedpreferences, and ma is the instance of the activity that has the shared preferences. Right now in activity called AddNameActivity.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In your case: is there an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Shared Preferences are not specific to any activity. It is common across application.**

In the File where you add a value to Shared Prefernces, add this code sample.

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putString("yourStringName", "this_is_the_saved_value");
  editor.commit();
```

In the file where you want to read the value (may be second activity), add this code sample.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_file_name",MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String string = prefs.getString("yourStringName","default_value");
```

You can use a default file to save/ read your preferences.

In that case, Just replace the first line of the two code snippets above by this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: thanks a lot! so just to clarify, if you create sharedpreferences in one activity, that sharedpreferences is also available in a different activity?

Comment: @user3798602, YES ... Also, If you are fine with the answer, mark it and close the loop.